# How to pass ownership of a Google API project's credentials to someone else?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

A colleague has registered OAuth 2.0 credentials on the Google API console, and I need to take over the administration. Is there a way to pass it over to me via the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He needs to transfer the project on [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/iam) to you.   The credentials are part of the project.

Upper left hand corner the hamburger menu look for iam-admin.  He can add you as owner and then you can remove him.